# "resetting" auto-increment on MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

Basically, I have a table. 'index' is the auto-incremented column. I would like to insert a row with an index of 1 and have the row that was previously at 1 go to 2, what was at 2 go to three and so on...

```
index | number
1     |  432
2     |   54
3     |   27


index | number
  1   |    x <---- new row
  2   |   432    |
  3   |   54     |indexes move down
  4   |   27     |
                 V
```

I am then deleting the oldest timestamped value in the same function to maintain the same number of rows in my table.

I haven't really found any good suggestions as to how to do this. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: What do you need this for? Touching a whole table for only one insertion sounds pretty unperformant.

Comment: why do you want to do this... auto increment is to increment value...

Comment: If you really need this and you want to do this for once you can do it with a PHP script for example. I can share an example code for you. But as Bergi's said, it's bad idea :)

Comment: Sounds like your table doesn't need the index to begin with.

Comment: I need an index so I can reference numbers to pull out and average via another code. The order and spacing between id's matters but the id doesn't really really matter. However, i would eventually have id's that were in the millions since the id would keep increasing...unless I can tell it not to